# Examples of Hamiltonian Cycle Problem / Traveling Salesman Problem in general grid graph form

Tags: computer-science, graph-theory, co.combinatorics

I understand that there is a polynomial algorithm to solve TSPs that are in solid grid graph form (grid graphs without holes).

I am particularly interested in the non-solid grid graph form of the HCP / TSP problems.  In other words, I would like to find some instances of the grid graphs that are non-solid.

Googling is to no avail.  Does anyone know of a good resource?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want? Examples of graphs?

Comment: Yes. Grid graphs with wholes.. I reckon I can do my own but I would like to find sources with known solutions.